Why Can't I use the session on different route in ExpressJS?
I am trying to get the user id with /GetUserID route and session returns undefined.Session is created on the /Login page but I can't access it on /GetUserID.
I use React at the front-end and axios for requests.
Session is not undefined when I print it on /Login.
app.use(session({
    secret: 'your_secret_key', 
    resave: false,             
    saveUninitialized: true,   
    cookie: { secure: false }  
}));

server.connect();
app.use(cookieParser());

//*Login
app.get("/Login",function(req,res){
    var Email=req.query.email_value.toString();
    var Password=req.query.password_value.toString();

    console.log("Email:"+Email);
    
    
    server.query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE Email=? AND Password=?",[Email,Password],function(error,user_count,fields){
        if(error){
            throw error;
        }
        else{
            var UserCount=parseInt(JSON.stringify(user_count[0]['COUNT(*)']));
            console.log("There are "+UserCount+" "+"users with the values of "+Email+" "+Password);

            if(UserCount==1){
                console.log("User:"+UserCount);
                req.session.user_email=Email;
                req.session.save();
            }
        

            res.json({user_count:UserCount});
        }
    });
});
app.get("/GetUserID",function(req,res){
    var session=req.session.user_email;

    console.log(session);
    
});

How can I solve it?

Hi, Please ensure that the login API has been invoked with credentials included. Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#including_credentials
